# Can not create TStream in Lazarus

Tags: pascal, lazarus

It fails in this simple example to:

```
      procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
      var
        ts: TStream;
      begin
        ts.Create; //<---- fails here
        ts.Free;
      end;
```

With error:

```
Project project1 raised exception class 'External: SIGSEGV'.
At address 10000DB38
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using the wrong code.  It should be

```
 procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
      var
        ts: TStream;
      begin
        ts := TStream.Create; //  If Lazarus supports  creation of Stream instances.
        ts.Free;
      end;
```

Until it is created, your variable `ts` simply contains junk from previous use of the stack.  You have to call the class's constructor to allocate the actual object on the heap and point your `ts` variable at it.

If Lazarus complains that it can't create an instance of TStream (it may treat it as an abstract class and I don't have Lazarus on this machine to check), try something like this instead:

```
 var
    ts: TMemoryStream;
  begin
    ts := TMemoryStream.Create; 
    ts.Free;
  end;
```

Instead of TMemoryStream, you could use any other concrete TStream-descendant class.

Comment: This is a duplicate hundreds of times over isn't it?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan:  I think the problem is that if an asker knew what to to ask, they wouldn't need to ask because they wouldn't have the problem in the first place.  Rather to my surprise, the increasingly-infallible google doesn't return the cause googling 'delphi create access violation' on its first page of hits.  These days, ime it seems to find the right answer in the first 2-3.

Comment: Not sure what your Google is doing, but here those search terms yield my proposed dupe as the first hit

Comment: @DavidHeffernan:  How did I miss that.  Looks like my googling was a spectacular failure (spectacular as in "of the spectacles")

Comment: I'm a long time Delphi user, and should have spottet the error...
But I have switched to Lazarus for this project for multi platform support, and was thrown off by the unfamiliar error message.
So googling: create External: SIGSEGV did not yield any useful hits in the first few pages.
If I had known that SIGSEGV = Access violation, my query would have been: delphi create access violation
That as @DavidHeffernan points out would have landed me on the article marked as dupe.

Comment: Yeah, all part of the learning curve. Segment violation signal.

Comment: Should I accept the duplicate as answer, or should I leave it as is so that other searching for "create External SIGSEGV" would find an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Was originaly trying this code:

```
memStream.Create;
```

But it should be:

```
memStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
```

Blah...